# ¿Como validar si una celda de fecha es sábado o domingo en C# Epplus?

Tags: c#, .net, epplus

tengo una consulta:

Lo que quiero es validar si la fecha es sábado o domingo y que me pinte la celda de color anaranjado.

la fecha a validar esta en el encabezado

```
public JsonResult ExportarResumenHoras()
        {
            DataTable data = GestionResumenHoras.Instancia.ListaResumenHoras();


            ExcelPackage pkg = new ExcelPackage();
            ExcelWorksheet ws = pkg.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Detalle(Semana)");

            //Carga los encabezados
            for (int c = 0; c < data.Columns.Count; c++)
            {
                ws.Cells[1,c+1].Value = data.Columns[c];
                ws.Cells[1,1,6,data.Columns.Count].AutoFilter = true;
            }


            Color colorDeCelda = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FCE811");
            //Carga los valores de acuerdo a la fecha registrada 
            if (data != null)
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < data.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < data.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        ws.Cells[i + 2, j + 1].Value = data.Rows[i][j];
                         if (j == 2)
                        {
                            ws.Cells[i + 2, j + 1].Value = Convert.ToInt32(data.Rows[i][j]);
                        }

                        else if (j == 3)
                        {
                            ws.Cells[i + 2, j + 1].Value = Convert.ToInt32(data.Rows[i][j]);
                            ws.Cells[i + 2, j + 1].Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                            ws.Cells[i + 2, j + 1].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Pink);
                        }
                        else if (j > 3)
                        {
                            if (data.Rows[i][j] != DBNull.Value)
                            {
                                if (Convert.ToDouble(data.Rows[i][j]) < 9.00)
                                {
                                    ws.Cells[i + 2, j + 1].Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                                    ws.Cells[i + 2, j + 1].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(colorDeCelda);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    ws.Cells[i + 2, j + 1].Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                                    ws.Cells[i + 2, j + 1].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Green);
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                ws.Cells[i + 2, j + 1].Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                                ws.Cells[i + 2, j + 1].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Red);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            ws.Cells[1, 1, data.Rows.Count + 1,data.Columns.Count].Style.Border.Top.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
            ws.Cells[1, 1, data.Rows.Count + 1, data.Columns.Count].Style.Border.Left.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
            ws.Cells[1, 1, data.Rows.Count + 1, data.Columns.Count].Style.Border.Right.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
            ws.Cells[1, 1, data.Rows.Count + 1, data.Columns.Count].Style.Border.Bottom.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;

            ws.Cells["A:AZ"].AutoFitColumns();



            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            pkg.SaveAs(memoryStream);
            memoryStream.Position = 0;

            var bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
            Session["archivoResumenHoras"] = bytes;
            return Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

He puesto una validación que si las celdas están vacías las pinte de color rojo pero ello no debe contemplar sábados ni domingos ya que esos días no son laborales.

En la imagen siguiente he validado si se trabajo 9 horas pinte de verde, si se trabajo menos amarillo, si las celdas están vacías en rojo y solo me faltaría que pinte de color anaranjado las celdas que sean fines de semana.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con base a la fecha que este tomando tu encabezado de la columna puedes hacer esto:

```
string iDate = "2019-10-05";//pasale aqui tu encabezado
 DateTime oDate = DateTime.Parse(iDate);
//le puedes dar un formato format = oDate.Day + " " + oDate.Month + "  " + oDate.Year 
DateTime fechaCurrent = oDate ;

//obtengo el nombre del dia
string nameday = fechaCurrent.ToString("dddd");
//aqui lo comparas con el if, toma en cuenta que tendras que si tu equipo esta en ingles, tienes que cambiar los nombres de los dias.
if(nameday == "Sabado" || nameday == "Domingo")
{
  //aqui pintas tus celdas
}
```

Quizas tenga errores, lo estoy escribiendo aca mismo, no lo estoy probando.

Comment: Pero las fechas están en números

Comment: puedes poner un ejemplo de fecha de como las tienes, no puedo ver tu imagen ya que estoy desde un servidor privado.

Comment: Ejemplo "2019-10-01" es una fecha en números pero de tipo string

Comment: ya edite la respuesta, aun asi posiblemente tenga errores, lo escrbi aca mismo, pero basicamente es convertir ese string a DateTime y seria todos.

Comment: Tienes la función [DayOfWeek](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/base-types/how-to-extract-the-day-of-the-week-from-a-specific-date) que te da el número de día de la semana a partir de una fecha. Te indica si es lunes, martes, etc.